# Echo '<li></li>' PHP

Tags: php, echo, html-lists

When I do this:

```
echo '<li></li>';
```

in php inside a `<ul>`, it breaks the rest of the php and results in `'; ?>` showing up on my site.

I'm trying to list journal entries and I've done it many times before, but it just doesn't seem to work now, which is very strange.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
mysql_select_db("lunatic");

?>

<title>Lunatic Cowboys - Gæstebog</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="headercont" class="container_12">
<div id="header" class="grid_12"></div>
<div id="navigation" class="grid_12">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Forside</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="historie.html">Historie</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="klubben.html">Klubben</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="vedtaegter.html">Vedtægter</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="dansetider.html">Dansetider</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="instruktoer.html">Instruktør</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="kalender.html">Kalender</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="galleri.html">Galleri</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="http://lunaticcowboys.blogspot.com/" target="_blank">Blog</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="gaestebog.html">Gæstebog</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li><li> -</li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="contcont" class="container_12">
<div id="content" class="grid_12">
<h1 id="overskrift">Gæstebog</h1>

</div>
<div id="guestbook" class="grid_7">
<h2>Se hilsner</h2>
<ul>
<?php 
    $eQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook");

    while($entries = mysql_fetch_assoc($eQuery)){
        echo "<li></li>";
    }
?>  
</ul>
</div>
<div id="add" class="grid_5">
<h2>Skriv en hilsen</h2>
<form id="guestbookform" method="post" action="add.html">
<fieldset>

<label for="name">Navn: </label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/><br />
<label for="email">Email: </label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email"/><br />
<label for="klub">Klub: </label>
<input type="text" id="klub" name="klub"/><br />
<label for="msg">Hilsen: </label>
<textarea name="msg" id="msg" rows="8" cols="39" onfocus="this.value=null;">Skriv din hilsen her</textarea><br />
<input type="button" onClick="javascript:addGreeting()" value="Send hilsen!" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<div id="copyright" class="grid_12">
<p>2011© Copyright Lunatic Cowboys<br />Udvikling og design af <a href="http://alexkotsc.co.cc">Alexander Kotschenreuther</a></p>
</div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function addGreeting(){ 

var aReq;

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    aReq= new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        aReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            aReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var klub = document.getElementById('klub').value;
var msg = document.getElementById('msg').value;

aReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(aReq.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = aReq.responseText;
    }
}
aReq.open('GET', 'add.php' + '?name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&klub=' + klub + '&msg=' + msg, true);
aReq.send(null);
```

}

No tags left unopened as you can see. I really don't get it, I've done this many times and I have never had a problem. What could be causing this?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH68S.png

Screenshot of Google Chrome developer tools: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KdOm.png

Its like when "rendered" the < ?php tags are considered < !-- like comments.

Comment: And what's the surrounding code? Are there any errors from PHP?

Comment: Please show your full code...

Comment: where is the `<code>echo ....</code>` ?

Comment: Pre tag was me trying to format correctly..

Comment: there is nothing in the code that you are showing that would break the rest of it. I suspect this isn't the actual code you're using, coz if it were the error wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Ill edit and put entire code in, as of now

Comment: @AlexKotsc check the html source of the page, maybe you'll see exact spot where the script is wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that above code, I think the problem lies somewhere else in the file. At what point in the HTML document do you see `'; ?>`? That sequence of characters does not appear in the above code sample, if anything it would be `"; } ?>`.

Comment: It appears just above "Se hilsner"

Comment: PLEASE don't use the `root` user to connect to your database in a production environment...

Comment: @DaveRandom- indeed. Alex, does php throw an error?

Comment: there's no `<ul>` tag between the php code qith `echo "<li></li>";`

Comment: What is wrong with using root when it local testing environment?

Comment: You might want to post `add.php` here, too.

Comment: PHP doesn't throw and error, i'll add screenshot

Comment: @AlexKotsc thanks for the screenshot - could you add html source? only the line that contains `'; } ?>`

Answer (score 3):

I think I have figured it out. PHP is not handling the request - no PHP code is being executed. If you view the source of the page, you will find that your entire PHP code is visible on the page.

Are you running this on a PHP enabled web server, and is the web server configured to pass the file extension you are using to PHP? Is the file a `.php` file or a `.html` file?

**EDIT**

If you want Apache to get PHP to handle `.html` files, add these lines to a .htaccess, or put them in httpd.conf and restart Apache:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

Comment: XAMPP, and .html. I have not used .html files with php before, i usually use .php. Could this be the problem?

Comment: It is definitely the problem. You can configure Apache to pass all `.html` files to PHP, but it does not do it by default. Change the files extension to `.php` and it will magically work...

Comment: @Alex I have just edited my answer to show you how get PHP to handle `.html` files. This will allow you to do it the way you were doing (if you want your files to have `.html` extensions).

Comment: Afaik the CMS can handle php files as well so no need, i will just change the file extensions and references to that page. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 1):

now there's no `<ul>` tag before or after the php code that is said to becausing the problem - maybe this is the wrong thing?

Comment: Formatting problems to get it onto here :) The problem persists